# Bypass forced JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am using a scripting API for making a script for a bot for a game I play, however whenever I override a bot manager, a JOptionPane appears that blocks execution until I close it, however I would like to run this script without human intervention, so I would like to bypass this pane.

I have tried to overwrite the JOptionPane class at runtime to no avail, and I have tried contacting the developer of the bot's API to add an override however he doesn't want to add an override.

I am open to any methods of resolving this (reflection, etc.), I was thinking of detecting the pane's title and force-closing it however that it way beyond my skill level.

Pane title: `Override Warning!`
I would add the pane text however it reveals personal information.

Comment: You could just create your own `JFrame` that you have full control of.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak sadly that wont work because it gets forced up as a child of the bot's main frame, which I can't control out of the limited methods for painting.

Comment: A child of main frame? `JFrame`s don't have hierarchy. Can't control out of painting methods? Of course you can, if you learn how `EventDispatchThread` works... But to be honest you shouldn't do such logic in `paint` method - that should do only painting.

Comment: If you know where the "issue" happens, you could run a batch-file that kills the window with the window-title of that JOptionPane. That could read the window titles of all the java applications until it get's to the one you do not want, kill it and then exit. However depending on how you do it, there might be a little delay before it closes leading to a short pop-up which might be distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possibility to suppress all JOptionPane dialogs. If you want to do it with some of them you probably need to provide additional check for dialog title.

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class CloseDialog implements Runnable {

    private final AWTEventListener hideOptionPaneListener = new AWTEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof WindowEvent) {
                processWindowEvent((WindowEvent) event);
            }
        }
    };

    private void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent we) {
        if (we.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED && we.getWindow() instanceof JDialog) {
            final JDialog dlg = (JDialog) we.getWindow();
            Component[] comps = dlg.getContentPane().getComponents();
            if (comps.length > 0 && comps[0] instanceof JOptionPane) { // probably also check dialog title
                dlg.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test frame");
        JButton button = new JButton("Show option pane");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frm, "Simple message");
            }
        });
        final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Suppress option pane");
        checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(hideOptionPaneListener, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
                } else {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(hideOptionPaneListener);
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel top = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        top.add(button);
        frm.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.add(checkBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.setSize(400, 200);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CloseDialog());
    }
}
```